# File upload path with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, testing, file-upload, ide, selenium-ide

I'm trying to upload files into Selenium IDE, I had read many forum posts but cannot find something working... So I'm searching for some help.
I'm testing a web app in which I need to upload pictures and videos.
In my scénario, i'm pressing a button which open a local file browser and select a file.
I've put  video sample at the root of my test folder in which there's my .side file.
In Selenium IDE i've tried :

| Command | Target       | Value                               |
| type    | id=importType| sample.mp4                          |
| type    | id=importType| /rel_path_from_side_file/sample.mp4 |
| type    | id=importType| /absolute_local_path/sample.mp4     |

During the test execution, the button is clicked and the file browser opens but I have to click manually on the sample.mp4 file to make test succeed so it's not automated at all.

I would like to automate this part of the test to use it in our CI/CD process.
If anyone sees my mistake or knows the solution, it would be awesome.
Thank you
Best regards
Brutal

Comment: Is website built in Wordpress by any chance?

Comment: Not at all @platipus_on_fire, It's a Saas software not a website, it's made with PHP + ReactJS